# insert @trigger().startTime into sql table in Azure DataFactory

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I have DataFactory where the source is CSV and the Destination is Azure SQL Data Warehouse

the Table in the Azure SQL Data Warehouse has an extra DateTime column for when the trigger was fired.

how I can have this to work when mapping the schema?

note: in Azure SQL Data Warehouse, it is not possible to have a column with default value GETDATE() as in Azure SQL Database.

the Column in SQL Data warehouse is "InsertedOn"

My Pipeline looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "Pipeline01",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "CopyCSVtoDW",
                "type": "Copy",
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "BlobSource",
                        "recursive": true
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "SqlDWSink",
                        "allowPolyBase": false,
                        "writeBatchSize": 10000
                    },
                    "enableStaging": false,
                    "enableSkipIncompatibleRow": false,
                    "translator": {
                        "type": "TabularTranslator",
                        "columnMappings": {
                            "Id": "pointconnectnativeid",
                            "ValueDate": "valuedate",
                            "Value": "value",
                            "InsertedOn": "insertedon",
                            "forecastDate": "forecastDate"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "SourceCSV",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "DestinationDW",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
}
```

here is my source:

```
{
    "name": "SourceCSV",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "skdwstorage",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "parameters": {
            "triggerDateTime": {
                "type": "Object",
                "defaultValue": "@trigger().startTime"
            }
        },
        "type": "AzureBlob",
        "structure": [
            {
                "name": "Id",
                "type": "String"
            },
            {
                "name": "ValueDate",
                "type": "DateTime",
                "format": "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"
            },
            {
                "name": "Value",
                "type": "Decimal"
            },
            {
                "name": "InsertedOn",
                "type": "DateTime",
                "description": "@trigger().startTime",
                "format": "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"
            },
            {
                "name": "forecastDate",
                "type": "DateTime",
                "format": "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"
            }
        ],
        "typeProperties": {
            "format": {
                "type": "TextFormat",
                "columnDelimiter": "|",
                "rowDelimiter": "\n",
                "quoteChar": "\"",
                "nullValue": "\\N",
                "encodingName": null,
                "treatEmptyAsNull": true,
                "skipLineCount": 0,
                "firstRowAsHeader": true
            },
            "fileName": "",
            "folderPath": "csv"
        }
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your .json trigger definition you can define a parameter called TriggerStartTime:

```
"parameters": {
" TriggerStartTime": "@trigger().startTime"
}
```

In your case for example:

```
{
    "name": "Pipeline01Trigger",
    "properties": {
        "runtimeState": "Started",
        "pipelines": [
            {
                "pipelineReference": {
                    "referenceName": "Pipeline01",
                    "type": "PipelineReference"
                },
                "parameters": {
                    "TriggerStartTime": "@trigger().startTime"
                }
            }
        ],
        "type": "ScheduleTrigger",
        "typeProperties": {
            "recurrence": {
                "frequency": "Hour",
                "interval": 1,
                "startTime": "2019-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                "timeZone": "UTC"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your Pipeline01 Parameter's section you have to set up a default value for the parameter.

After in your copy activity you can Map this parameter with:

```
@pipeline().parameters.TriggerStartTime
```

In your case something like:

```
"columnMappings": {
    "Id": "pointconnectnativeid",
    "ValueDate": "valuedate",
    "Value": "value",
    "InsertedOn": "@pipeline().parameters.TriggerStartTime",
    "forecastDate": "forecastDate"
}
```

Here you can find some information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-schedule-trigger#pass-the-trigger-start-time-to-a-pipeline

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions

Comment: in theory, I understand your answer, not sure where exactly to add them ... I posted my pipeline

Comment: @Data-Base I have edited the answer I hope now it's clearly